# How to create a submit button for multiple forms

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I was wondering how can I create a submit button to submit multiple forms.

I have 3 forms that could have been all together but for design purposes i decided to separate them now i was wondering how can i create a submit button to submit the data via php and mysql. I would put the three forms on here but it wouldn't matter considering the fact that they could have been combined but for design purposes i had to separate them. And if there is a way to create that button without javascript or jquery please tell me if not its still ok.

Comment: Put everything in a single form tag

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need 3 separate forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without javascript or jQuery? Highly unlikely.

Its a fact that enclosing all the fields in a single `<form>` tag won't affect your design.

& if your css is based on the form ids, you might try enclosing your separate forms in separate `<div>` tags instead!
That should work out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Each form submit is a trigger for the browser to do a POST or GET to that form's action, and it will only send the data in that form. The only thing you can do is put the form around whatever tabbed or accordion control you've added.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event with button and on click create a data set by serializing all forms and save using ajax.

A little example

```
var formsData = {}
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("form").each(function(){
           formsData[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).serialize();
      });
});
```

To post this serialized data

```
var dataToPost = "data=";
for (var key in formsData) {
    dataToPost += key + "|";
}
```

Just attach this `dataToPost` with ajax.

This is a pretty long idea. Why you can't put everything in one form tag?

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Nice but did you miss the no javascript and no jquery part?